# Determine what Octants a line segment passes through

Tags: c#, geometry

It's been 20+ years since I took any sort of math class so I'm super rusty. I am using the following code to determine which Octant a point is located at relative to the provided center:

```
public static int GetOctant(Vector2 center, Vector2 target)
{
    var adjusted = target - center;
    int oct = 0;

    if (adjusted.Y < 0)
    {
        adjusted *= -1; // rotate 180
        oct += 4;
    }
    if (adjusted.X < 0)
    {
        adjusted = new Vector2(adjusted.Y, -adjusted.X); // rotate cw 90
        oct += 2;
    }
    if (adjusted.X < adjusted.Y)
        oct++;

    return oct;
}
```

I do this for both sides of my line, that gives me the starting and ending octants.  ***If they are more than 1 octant apart, then I also need to know which other octants the line passes through. But I can't figure out how to do that.***

I am hoping for a method like this:

```
private static int[] InOctants(Vector2 relativeCenter, Vector2 startPoint, Vector2 endPoint)

private static bool IsInOctant(int oct, Vector2 center, Vector2 startPoint, Vector2 endPoint)
```

My code (which is very non-mathmatical) looks like this (a `Segment` is just 2 `Vectors2`):

```
private static List<Segment>[] PlaceInOctants(Vector2 center, IEnumerable<Segment> segments)
{
    // We are creating lists of segments, 1 for each octant.
    // Each list will contain any segment that touches that octant
    var octants = new List<Segment>[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < octants.Length; i++)
        octants[i] = new List<Segment>();

    foreach (Segment s in segments)
    {
        // Get the octant for the start/end points of the segments
        var octantA = GetOctant(center, s.PointA);
        var octantB = GetOctant(center, s.PointB);
        if (octantA > octantB)
        {
            var tempOct = octantA;
            octantA = octantB;
            octantB = tempOct;
        }

        // Add the first segment to the first octants list
        if (!octants[octantA].Contains(s))
            octants[octantA].Add(s);

        // If octA & octB are different
        if (octantA != octantB)
        {
            // We add the segment to the other list
            if (!octants[octantB].Contains(s))
                octants[octantB].Add(s);

            var diff = octantA - octantB;
            if (diff < 0)
                diff += 8;
            if (diff > 4)
                diff = 8 - diff;
            // If A & B are 4 spaces apart (very rare) it's difficult to get 
            // the octants they pass through so we just add the segment 
            // to all the octants (it's going to pass through 5 out of 8 anyway)
            // !!!! I'd like to do this right though  !!!!
            if (diff == 4)
                for (int i = 0; i < octants.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (octantA != i && octantB != i && !octants[i].Contains(s))
                        octants[i].Add(s);
                }
            else
            {
                if (diff >= 2)
                {
                    var oct = Math.Abs(diff) < 4
                        ? octantA < 7 ? octantA + 1 : 0
                        : octantA > 0 ? octantA - 1 : 7;

                    octants[oct].Add(s);
                }
                if (diff == 3)
                {
                       var oct = Math.Abs(diff) > 4
                            ? octantB < 7 ? octantB + 1 : 0
                            : octantB > 0 ? octantB - 1 : 7;
                        octants[oct].Add(s);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return octants;
}
```

I'm using C# at the moment, but can convert from just about anything.

Someone voted to close this because it wasn't clear what I was asking... To make it clear. I am using a hack to determine what octants a line segment passes through, and in some cases I just ignore it and add the segment to all my lists.  I would like to tighten up that code and do it right (using geometry) if possible. I also want to avoid using atan2 because it is slow.

Comment: Here is some python I found: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95550/determining-which-octant-has-a-specific-point

Comment: Does your line pass through center point?

Comment: Vector2 is 2d isn't it? so are looking for quadrants?

Comment: In 2d you want to find out where you cross each axis if at all. In 3d you ask the same question about the axis planes..

Comment: Do you mean line or line segment ? A line doesn't have "sides".

Comment: Yes. line segment. Updated the title.

Comment: @Mr.B - Thanks, that helped me get rid of the atan2 - updated question with new method

Answer (score 0):

The octants are delimited by the lines `x = 0`, `y = 0`, `x = y`, `x = -y`. You can find the intersections with a given line such as `a.x + b.y + c = 0` by solving the corresponding systems.

For instance

```
a.x + b.y + c = 0
x = y
```

gives `x = y = - c / (a + b)`.

In general, there will be four intersections, delimiting five octants that are crossed. You can identify to which octant the intersections belong by looking at the signs of `x`, `y`, `x + y`, `x - y`.

The complete discussion takes some effort, but I am sure you will manage.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I understand about 20% of what is written there.  I'm not sure where I would get the value for c.  Even with that though I'm still not sure how I would get that to work in my code.

Comment: For a line segment, you'd better use `X = X0 + t (X1 - X0), Y = Y0 + t (Y1 - Y0)`

Comment: Where are you getting t from?

Comment: t is an unknown that you determine from the equations and tells you where you are along the segment.